# How do I call a subroutine from a string variable?

Tags: vb.net, string, converters, subroutine

Using VB.Net 4 and VS2012

I have a Module with some logic in it like this:

```
Module Mod1
    If x = 1 then 
       Mod2("Mod3","save_it")
    else
       Mod2("Mod4","edit_it")
    end if
End Module

Module Mod2(which_mod, which_action)
     ' call the correct subroutine
     which_mod.which_action()
End Module
```

How do I use the strings to call the correct subroutine from different modules?

Comment: In what language is that valid syntax? It's not VB.NET for sure. You cannot add logic to the module body, you have to use a method.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's your underlying need?

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree. This does look like an [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: The syntax was abbreviated for brevity and just to demonstrate the issue. Not to be comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the System.Reflection namespace, it contains a class called MethodInfo.

You can obtain the MethodInfo, for a given object, using the method name, then invoke it:

```
Dim method As MethodInfo = obj.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public)
method.Invoke()
```

Answer (score 0):

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22x2chfx.aspx)

There is a function `CallByName` which does exactly that.

The function accepts 4 parameters:

- object/class
- function/procname
- calltype (CallType.method, CallType.Get, CallType.Set)
- (optional): parameter (in arrayformat)

The first parameter (object/class) can't be a string, so we have to cast your string to an object. The best way to do this is

```
Dim MyInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(which_mod))
```

So for your code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.CallType
Imports System.Reflection
Class Mod1
    If x = 1 then 
       Mod2("Mod3","save_it")
    else
       Mod2("Mod4","edit_it")
    end if
End Class

Module Mod2(which_mod, which_action)
     ' call the correct subroutine
     Dim MyInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(which_mod))
     CallByName(MyInstance , which_action, CallType.Method)
End Module
```

Comment: Very close. The `which_mod` variable is an `Object` and not a `String`.

Comment: That's where a dictionary of strings to objects will come in to play. There will need to be some sort of object look-up to work from strings.

Comment: @Enigmativity I used the `System.Reflection` library, that is also mentioned in @trucket_jim his answer to get the object.

Comment: You can't use reflection to get object references - you need object references **first** to be able to use reflection. That is, unless you're using reflection to actually create the instances, then this is looking more like dependency injection.